# I need Regex to mask email address in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to mask email address abcdef@gmail.com=> abXXX@gmail.com in JavaScript

i used /(?<=.{2}).(?=[^@]*?@)/ regex but not working in internet explorer and Mozilla so i need regex which works in all browser(JavaScript)

maskedEmail = stringObj.replace(/(?<=.{2}).(?=[^@]*?@)/g, "X");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this option, which avoids using a lookbehind:

```js
var email = "abcdef@gmail.com";
var output = email.replace(/^(.{2})[^@]+/, "$1XXX");
console.log(email);
console.log(output);
```

Note that I took a slight shortcut here by always representing the third character of the email name onwards with static `XXX`.  We could try to keep the same length name, but it would take more work.  I actually advise against doing that, because it partially defeats the purpose of masking the email, by giving away the actual length.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of regex for this simple operation. This should work equally well:

```js
var emailAddress = "john.doe@gmail.com"
    
    function maskEmail(email) {
      let split = email.split('@')
      return email.substr(0,1) + new Array(split[0].length - 1).fill('x').join('') + "@" + split[1]
    }
    
    console.log(maskEmail(emailAddress))
```